# How to make VPS hosting using vmware, and etc

Tags: 18.04, virtualization, vmware, vps

I need to make some VPSs on my DS. How can I use it, which virtualization software is the best, how can I control, manage them? I would be very appreciated if you would be helpful for me! Thank you!

Comment: Can you add more info?

Comment: What type of info? I need to "divide" my Dedicated Server. I read that I need to use virtualization software, such as vmware. But I haven't found anything about it.

Comment: There are several ways to create a virtualization host. VMware, Proxmox, Docker as to mention some. I would recommend Proxmox, a KVM/QUEMU virtualization based on Debian with a nice web GUI.

Comment: Can you please explain to me. I will try it.

Comment: There's many solutions. From simple tools with low complexity and easy configuration, to complex tools with automation and so on. What are you trying to achieve? That bears in heavily on the solution. Note that I also believe this question is slightly off topic here. A ontopic question would be how to configure this on Ubuntu, not an open question about how to virtualize...